# Adding select dropdown to dialog window

Tags: aem

I'm having difficulty on how to add options to a selection for dialog.

The Adobe notes I'm reading are here: [CQ.form.Selection](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection)

Scrolling down to `options : Object[]/String` will show you two ways to reference the options to provide the said selection, via object or string. I am trying to use the object method. The format example they provide is sufficient.

```
[
    {
        value: "pink", // all types except "combobox"
        text: "Pink",
        qtip: "Real Pink" // "select" and "combobox"
    }
]
```

However, CRXDE Lite does not allow me to select or type Object when adding a new property, and this is where I am at a loss. Is there another way to enter a complex value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding options as an `Object[]` would be done via a child node, rather than properties. (In fact anywhere you see an `Object` in the API, think `node` rather than `property`.)

In your `dialog.xml` file, this would be done as follows:

```
<selectList
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    defaultValue="0"
    fieldLabel="Number"
    name="./number"
    type="select"
    xtype="selection">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <one
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="One"
            value="1"/>
        <two
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Two"
            value="2"/>
        <three
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Three"
            value="3"/>
        <four
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Four"
            value="4"/>
    </options>
</selectList>
```

In CRXDE, this can be achieved by creating the same hierarchy:

1. Right-clicking your selection node and choosing **Create** > **Node**.
2. Give this node a `jcr:primaryType` of `cq:WidgetCollection`. This will hold your option values.
3. Individual options can now be added as child nodes of this, with a `jcr:primaryType` of `nt:unstructured`.
4. Place your properties (`value`, `text`, `qtip`) on these child nodes.

Comment: Quick side tip: To change a drop down to radio buttons, in selectList you would change `type="select"` to `type="text"`.